# MacTex new install not showing section references

Tags: mactex, mac

Here is a simple example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{boat.jpg}
  \caption{A boat.}
  \label{fig:boat1}
\end{figure}

Figure \ref{fig:boat1} shows a boat.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Notice it shows "Figure ?? shows a boat."

The documentation I have for the "exam" class does the same thing. Throughout the document references to other Sections have double ??.

Any help would be appreciated.

Happy Thursday!

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that it does it with Figure and Section references and I am using TexShop/LaTex to typeset it.

Comment: Did you compile twice?

Comment: Mico, that did the trick. Thanks I didn't know I needed to do that.